# How many coaches have won test rugby against New Zealand in New Zealand?

Tags: rugby-union

With the South African Springboks beating the New Zealand All Blacks on 15 September 2018, Rassie Erasmus has joined an elite group of rugby coaches who can say they have won test rugby in New Zealand. That made me wonder how many coaches in the world have won test rugby in New Zealand in the professional era?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this query on ESPN Scrum](http://stats.espnscrum.com/statsguru/rugby/stats/index.html?class=1;home_or_away=1;result=2;spanmin1=26+Aug+1995;spanval1=span;team=8;template=results;type=team;view=results), New Zealand has lost 10 times at home since August 26th, 1995 (the beginning of the professional era). The coaches aren't mentioned but can be retrieved from Wikipedia.

```
Team            Score     Opposition    Ground          Date        Coach
===========================================================================
New Zealand     3   13  v South Africa  Wellington      25 Jul 1998 Nick Mallett
New Zealand     23  27  v Australia     Christchurch    1 Aug 1998  Rod Macqueen
New Zealand     23  24  v Australia     Wellington      5 Aug 2000  Rod Macqueen
New Zealand     15  23  v Australia     Dunedin         11 Aug 2001 Eddie Jones
New Zealand     13  15  v England       Wellington      14 Jun 2003 Sir Clive Woodward
New Zealand     28  30  v South Africa  Dunedin         12 Jul 2008 Peter de Villiers
New Zealand     22  27  v France        Dunedin         13 Jun 2009 Marc Lièvremont
New Zealand     29  32  v South Africa  Hamilton        12 Sep 2009 Peter de Villiers
New Zealand     21  24  v Lions         Wellington      1 Jul 2017  Warren Gatland
New Zealand     34  36  v South Africa  Wellington      15 Sep 2018 Rassie Erasmus
```

Two coaches pulled it off twice, so the answer to your question is **8**.

Comment: Could I ask you to update this answer?